# Logging Chrooted SFTP user activity

Tags: logging, sftp, rsyslog, chroot

I have been trying to log SFTP activity by Chrooted user.
I have not been able to log a single line so far for any chrooted user. For regular users it works.

My current settings:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l VERBOSE

ClientAliveInterval 180
PasswordAuthentication no

Match Group sftpclients
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp -f AUTH -l VERBOSE
```

/etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
$AddUnixListenSocket        /home/sftp.log.socket
$AddUnixListenSocket        /home/sftp/dev/log.socket
$AddUnixListenSocket        /home/sftp/user1/dev/log.socket
$AddUnixListenSocket        /home/sftp/user2/dev/log.socket

:programname, isequal, "internal-sftp" -/var/log/sftp2.log
:programname, isequal, "internal-sftp" ~
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/sftp.conf:

```
 input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/home/sftp/log2.socket" CreatePath="on")
 if $programname == 'internal-sftp' then /var/log/sftp3.log
```

Each user has their //dev/ directory bound to /dev: 
`mount --bind /dev /home/sftp/<user>/dev` as well as the sockets defined in `rsyslog.conf` / `sftp.conf`

**Question** I have tried basically every suggestion I have found, what might I be missing in my setup to log chrooted users?

Comment: It works on OpenBSD, so it must be relevant to your Linux settings, ie. rsyslog and how you create /dev/syslog in chroot.

Comment: I'm running Debian 8 (Jessie). I've basically done all options for logging from a chroot jail I know of. Socket definitions in `rsyslog.conf / sftp.conf`and directly binding `/dev/' to users dev folder.

Comment: You can try strace to trace your processes to see what they try to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that `/dev/log` is a file that can be shared via bind-mounting `/dev` is incorrect for most modern linux distributions using *systemd*. Therefore, mounting your systems `/dev` into your chroot has little value.

```
$ file /dev/log
/dev/log: symbolic link to /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
```

Since /run is not available like that in the chroot (*and should not be*), sftp-server trying to write to `/dev/log` will consider that a broken symlink.

Instead, use `input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/opt/bindmount/dev/log")` to create an additional socket (which you can then bind-mount such that all chroots see it at `/dev/log`).

You generally should not share full `/dev` access to chroot anyway, the whole point of chroot is limiting attack surface.

---

Bonus: You can write your `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-sftp.conf` config like this (filter by "host name", which you can arbitrarily choose)

```
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/opt/bindmount/dev/log", HostName="sftp")
if $hostname == 'sftp' then /var/log/sftp.log
&stop
```

This means that if you deploy other chroots, limited to other commands (such as a `git-shell`), you can still have all messages from chroot in the same spot, even if other programs write to `/dev/log`.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not use rsyslogd and use only journald from systemd, you can do the following (source https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot#Logging)

(Please replace `<OPENSSH_CHROOT_PATH>` with the chroot path configured in openssh, ie: in your case : `/home/sftp/%u`)

```
# mkdir /<OPENSSH_CHROOT_PATH>/dev
# chmod 755 /<OPENSSH_CHROOT_PATH>/dev
# touch /<OPENSSH_CHROOT_PATH>/dev/log
```

And bind-mount journald socket with :

```
# mount --bind /run/systemd/journal/dev-log /<OPENSSH_CHROOT_PATH>/dev/log
```

And If you need it permanently, do not forget to add this bind-mount in your /etc/fstab with :

/etc/fstab:

```
(…)
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log /<OPENSSH_CHROOT_PATH>/dev/log none bind   0   0
(…)
```

You can now see internal-sftp logging with journalctl :

```
# journalctl -f
```